# How to query data for a certain data range in MySQL

Tags: mysql

We are using MySQL, and the table have a column named 'createdat` which means the time when the record are inserted.

Now we want to get data within 10 days from its created time.

Something like this:

```
select xx from table where time_of_now - createdat<= 10
```

I wonder if MySQL support this kind of query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DATEDIFF` to get the difference between 2 dates in days, like so:

```
select xx 
from table 
where datediff(now(),createdat) <= 10
```

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

Comment: Using dateDiff is not such a good idea here because it will make the index on `createdat` unusable. The diff for all dates will be calculated first and then that will be compared with 10 (a linear scan)

Answer (score 0):

```
select xx from table where createdat >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 day
```